# SmartTarget2014 UserControls not evaluating

Tags: content-delivery, smarttarget, 2013-sp1

The published result of a SmartTarget enabled page(below) has properly resolved the TCDL tags, but does not, however, evaluate the SmartTarget user controls at runtime. The below code is rendered to the page, minus the Page Language declaration, as is and unevaluated.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
```

```
<SmartTarget:promotions region="ST" var="promotion" maxItems="1"> 
    <SmartTarget:itemTemplate> 
        <SmartTarget:promotionalItems> 
            <SmartTarget:itemTemplate> 
                    <tridion:ComponentPresentation pageURI="tcm:3151-18143-64" componentURI="${item.componentUri}" templateURI="${item.templateUri}"/> 
            </SmartTarget:itemTemplate> 
        </SmartTarget:promotionalItems> 
    </SmartTarget:itemTemplate> 
    <SmartTarget:fallbackContent> 

        <br>Fallback content goes here.</br>

    </SmartTarget:fallbackContent> 
</SmartTarget:promotions>
```

The web.config for the app is as follows

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
    <globalization fileEncoding="utf-8" requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" culture="en-US"/>
<pages>
    <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add tagPrefix="tridion" namespace="Tridion.ContentDelivery.Web.UI" assembly="Tridion.ContentDelivery" />
        <add tagPrefix="SmartTarget" namespace="Tridion.SmartTarget.Web.UI" assembly="Tridion.SmartTarget" />
    </controls>
</pages>

</system.web>
<system.webServer>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
    <add type="Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.HttpModule" name="Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.HttpModule" /> 
</modules>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The relevant snippet from my smarttarget_conf below shows that the case of the ST user controls is valid and matching.

```
   <Tcdl>
        <Prefix>
            <Java>SmartTarget</Java>
            <DotNet>SmartTarget</DotNet>
            <Jstl>
                <Core>c</Core>
            </Jstl>
        </Prefix>
```

Another possibly related issue deals with the session and smart target cartridges delivered with SmartTarget. When I add those cartridges the app completely breaks with no error and renders a blank html page. This issue combined with the non-evaluation of the SmartTarget controls lead me to believe I may have a corrupt SmartTarget download.

Is there something else that anyone can think of that I might be missing here? Also let me know if there is any other information or configs I can provide to help the diagnosis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you've asked it to render JSP tags but your site is running ASP.NET. 
You should change the Target Language of your Publication Target to ASP.NET and republish.

Comment: Took me a second to figure out how you discovered this... then saw it - attribute case. Well spotted.

Comment: There's also a "var" attribute and no "runat=server" attribute (the latter being the real reason why it doesn't work), but yeah :)

Comment: @PeterKjaer the target language on my publication target is ASP.NET.

Comment: @NunoLinhares the case looks funny because I changed it in the smarttarget_config to match the web.config example from LiveContent. I edited to show the snippet from the smarttarget_conf

Comment: @PeterKjaer good catch. I totally missed that detail as I was focused more on the other new syntax from the latest version of ST. Having the publication language set correctly to .NET, is there any other way this could happen?

Comment: Your deployer_conf can force a language too - check the `<TCDLEngine>` section in it

Comment: What Nuno said. Only other thing that springs to mind is that you might have another target that is also publishing to the same location but a different target language (we see this on test / dev machines sometimes)

Comment: @NunoLinhares That was it! The one thing I managed not to check. This is a POC application in a sandbox and I obviously copied a deployer from a java app instead of .NET. It also appeared that either the session or smarttarget cartridge was corrupt in the SmartTarget download. I re-downloaded and installed the new cartridges and the call to Fredhopper is now being made.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the steps I'd take to troubleshoot your issue:

1. configure your log file to capture your smart target events (documented [here](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_SmartTarget_2014-v1/GUID-C7D67800-E4C7-40B8-9B19-C7AF0420F2E0)) - you can see the request made to SmartTarget plus you'll see any errors reported
2. use the preview tool within the business manager to test that your triggers are working correctly.
3. Write a bit of code to check that your expected values exist in the ambient data framework, i've dropped an example [here](http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/see-all-the-values-contained-within-your-ambient-data-framework)

Once you've done these three, perhaps update your question with more information to help solve it, or if you solve it, please provide the answer for every one else.

Comment: I have already been through steps 1 and 2, but stopped there when I realized from the logging that the call to ST wasn't happening. This is when I realized the user controls were not being evaluated. I'm still trying to solve that issue.

Comment: ah well, i'll leave the info there, might be useful to someone one one day :)

Comment: Totally agree. These are the defacto steps I take as should anyone in debugging SmartTarget. When they have their deployers correctly setup, unlike I did here :)